# swift firebase nested children count

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
groups
--group1(autoid)
---subgroup1(autoid)
----id
----ownerId
----description
--group2(autoid)
---subgroup2(autoid)
----id
----ownerId
----description
```

In a structure like over here i have to count all occurrencies of ownerId that are equal to my id (currentUserId) in all groups, can somebody help me?

what i've done so far:

```swift
root.child("groups").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        var count = 0
        for child in result {
            let orderID = child.key as String //get autoID
            self.root.child("groups/\(orderID)/").queryOrdered(byChild: "ownerId").queryEqual(toValue: self.currentUserId).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot!) in
                print(snapshot.childrenCount, "quanti sono")
                count += (Int(snapshot.childrenCount))
                print(count)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

with this i can get a count but it updates all cycles... i need i need the final value outside

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would be helpful to update your question with an actual data example, your expected result, and your actual result.  See how to craft a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want to say that how you are storing the number of groups is the issue. This query involves a sub query and is overly complicated to get a simple result. Why not just store the number of groups a user is a member of directly in the database? Example Users -> UID -> GroupMemberCount? Then you can just update this value when a user joins / leaves a group. It would make the whole process easier. Also snapshot.childrenCount iterates over all of the children so it might not be efficient if the user is a member of a lot of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important aspect of Firebase Structures is [denormalizing](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) or flattening the structure. Denormalized data generally makes queries much easier and while conceptually the structure you are using works for some tasks, it makes doing the query you want challenging.

So, I would suggest an alternate structure that would make the query super simple, and not loose other functionality.

A change to the structure like this:

```
groups
  group1: true
  group2: true

subgroups
  subgroup1(autoid)
     id
     ownerId
     description
     belongs_to_group: "group1"
  subgroup2(autoid)
     id
     ownerId
     description
     belongs_to_group: "group2"
```

Then if you want to count all of subgroups with a particular ownerId

```
let subGroupsRef = self.ref.child("subgroups")
let query = subGroupsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "ownerId").queryEqual(toValue: "their id")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    let count = snapshot.childrenCount
    print(count)
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comment, here's an way to get the count based on your current structure. It's pretty brute force and the code could be reduced considerably but I left it verbose for readability

```
let groupsRef = self.ref.child("groups")
groupsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    var count = 0
    for groupChild in snapshot.children {
        let groupSnap = groupChild as! DataSnapshot
        for subGroupChild in groupSnap.children {
            let subGroupSnap = subGroupChild as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = subGroupSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let uid = dict["owner_id"] as! String
            if uid == "uid_0" {
                count += 1
                print(count)
            }
        }
    }
    print("total found \(count)")
})
```

Where this fails is if you have a lot of nodes as they are all initially loaded in (by .value) so it could be iterated over in code. If it's a few thousand it works well and is very fast.

Comment: thnx Jay, your way is a good way but at the moment i cannot change the db structure, with my code (the one you can see) i'm able to get the count, if i add a completition maybe i can read the final count only... you think?

Comment: @Marco Gotcha. I edited my answer with a solution. It works but I am not super fond of it as I don't like to present an answer that could fail based on having to load too many nodes. I may have another option in the morning.

Comment: Thnx @Jay it works perfectly, le me know if you find a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this step by doing a single `observe` of `.childAdded` type. The `.childAdded` on an sub child, in your example `groups`, is like a for loop that iterate all nodes.

With this configuration you can append a `.queryOrdered(byChild:)` and a `.queryEqual(toValue:)`:

```
ref.child("groups")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "ownerID")
    .queryEqual(toValue: 123)
    .observe(.childAdded)
{ (snap) in
    print(snap)
}
```

After that, if you want to count all this child, you need to add a property on your class

This is a test example:

[image]

To optimize performance remember to add a `.indexOn` rule on your firebase app:

```
"groups" : {
  ".indexOn" : "ownerID"
}
```

Hope this help you ;)

Comment: Thnx Giuseppe but i wrote an error in my question, i miss a nested child, structure is that one:

[code] groups
 -KwW2gHCbWzPCQpmbfhu
 --Kxgqyhgqyg2CjKIEln1addclose
 ---ownerId: [code]

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work. The query you're suggesting will query the direct child node of *ownerId* of each group1, group2. If you look at the structure group1 and group2, they don't have an ownerID child node. It's a child of a child node. /groups/group1/ownerId, not /groups/ownerId.